# click event for dynamically added button in a row is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

i have created tables dynamically using JQuery. I have added button(image) to each row. On clicking particular button, i need to assign some functionality(ex: alert) to that particular button alone. Here only alert is working for button in first row only. No click event is triggered for buttons in other rows.

And i cannot get the proper row number in alert whose button is clicked.

my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var content = '<table>'
    content += '<tr><td>'
    content += '<img class="inline" id="submitbtn" src="../../submit.png" />';
    content += '</td></tr>'
    content += '</table>'
    $("#mainSection").append(content);
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
      alert("row" + i + "Data Submitted");
    });
  }
});
my html; < div id = 'mainSection' > < /div>
```

Comment: ID should not replicate. Your code will produce 10 tags with same ID. Use class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a delegated event handler for dynamic content as events are attached on load, before the element was created. Note also that you will end up with a lot of duplicate `id` attributes where you should really be using a `class`. Finally, the `i` variable will not be available inside the click handler, so you need to traverse the DOM to get the `index()` of the closest `tr` element. Try this:

```
for (i=1; i<10; i++) {
    var content = '<table>'
    content += '<tr><td>'
    content += '<img class="inline submitbtn" src="../../submit.png" />';
    content += '</td></tr>'
    content += '</table>'
    $("#mainSection").append(content);
}

$("#mainSection").on('click', '.submitbtn', function() {
    alert("row" + $(this).closest('table').index() + "Data Submitted" );
});
```

Comment: How is this going to work if there are 10 "#mainSection" on html?

Comment: Alright, speedy people. Check out the update. There was far more issues than multiple `id` attributes, like the use of `i` in the handler.

Comment: one last nitpick - since there's one table/row per button - you probably want the .closest('table') and not the tr :P

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ what if there is multiple buttons in a row. which will be the closest?

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan: i am getting row number as "0" in alert for every rows.

Comment: @msg check my update thanks to wirey - `closest('table').index()`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

And change id to class on submitbtn

```
$(document).on('click', '.submitbtn', function() {
    alert("row" + i + "Data Submitted" );     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do whatever you are looking for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   for(i=1; i<10; i++)
   {
    var content = '<table>'
    content += '<tr><td>'
    content += '<img class="submitbtn inline" src="../../submit.png" />';
    content += '</td></tr>'
    content += '</table>'
    $("#mainSection").append(content);
   }

$(".submitbtn").click(function() {
      alert("row" + $(this).closest('td').parent()[0].sectionRowIndex + "Data Submitted" );     });
  }

    });
```

Comment: you have used two classes in img tag,which is not working. I had done same mistake previously.